# Breakout Sessions

Tags: civievent, registration

Can you tell me how to set up Civi Events registration to allow attendees to sign up for breakout sessions? One set of sessions includes one that requires an additional fee.

Answer (score 2):

have a good look at what a Price Set can do for you. You can set up $0 options for the break-out sessions that have no price, and ones that have a price. You can set limits on how many registrations each session can take.

Answer (score 1):

I'd set these up as Event Types with a custom field of type Event called Parent Event.